# Unable to use Nativescript plugins on Svelte native( nativescript-videoplayer)

Tags: nativescript, svelte, svelte-component, svelte-native

I have been trying to use the nativescript-videoplayer plugin with svelte native.

the documentation says to use the registerNativeViewElement to use nativescript plugins.
Even after registration, I'm unable to use the component

```js
//app.ts
import { svelteNativeNoFrame} from 'svelte-native';

import { registerNativeViewElement } from "svelte-native/dom";
import { Video } from "nativescript-videoplayer";

registerNativeViewElement('Video', () =>  Video);

import App from './App.svelte';
svelteNativeNoFrame(App, {});
```

```html
//App.svelte
<frame class="app">
    <page>
       <Video src="http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/BigBuckBunny.mp4"/>
    </page>    
</frame>

<script lang="ts">
 //import Home from './components/Home.svelte';

</script>
```

this is the error I get

```
  System.err: An uncaught Exception occurred on "main" thread.
  System.err: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{org.nativescript.calmness/com.tns.NativeScriptActivity}: com.tns.NativeScriptException: 
  Calling js method onCreate failed
  System.err: ReferenceError: Video is not defined
  System.err:
  System.err: StackTrace:
  System.err: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{org.nativescript.calmness/com.tns.NativeScriptActivity}: com
  .tns.NativeScriptException: Calling js method onCreate failed
  System.err: ReferenceError: Video is not defined
  System.err:   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3676)
  System.err:   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3813)
  System.err:   at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:101)
  System.err:   at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
  System.err:   at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
  System.err:   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2308)
  System.err:   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
  System.err:   at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)
  System.err:   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
  System.err:   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7898)
  System.err:   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
  System.err:   at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548)
  System.err:   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:936)
  System.err: Caused by: com.tns.NativeScriptException: Calling js method onCreate failed
  System.err: ReferenceError: Video is not defined
  System.err:   at com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethodNative(Native Method)
  System.err:   at com.tns.Runtime.dispatchCallJSMethodNative(Runtime.java:1302)
  System.err:   at com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethodImpl(Runtime.java:1188)
  System.err:   at com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethod(Runtime.java:1175)
  System.err:   at com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethod(Runtime.java:1153)
  System.err:   at com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethod(Runtime.java:1149)
  System.err:   at com.tns.NativeScriptActivity.onCreate(NativeScriptActivity.java:57)
  System.err:   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8290)
  System.err:   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8269)
  System.err:   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1384)
  System.err:   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3657)
  System.err:   ... 12 more
```

Comment: managed to fix this, svelte-natives' registerNativeViewElement() changes the name of the element to lowercase, so an element registered as 'Video' can be used with <video ></video>.